# AngularJS routing for dynamic urls, how?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to understand how can i configure my angularJS routing given the following case:

We have a search page where we display the search results based on tags provided (1..n tags). we would like that a user to be able to parse enter a url as the following and our system to do the search and show the respective results.

The url format should be:

`http://mywebsite.com/search/<term1>/<term2>/<termN>`...so it could be different number of terms.

I was looking into the route provide and couldn't figure out a way to do it dynamically.

i saw that i could put in the routeprovid:

`.when('/search/:searchParams'`,... but that handles only when i have one term...is there anyway to configure it to take as many terms as is given?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you at all? Seems to support dynamic routing and you could probably cut apart the :name parameter to do what you wish, perhaps.

http://gregorypratt.github.io/AngularDynamicRouting/

Ken

Answer (score 0):

You could try [base64ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.atob) your searchParams:

```
.when('/search/:searchParams', {controller:'SearchCtrl'})

function SearchCtrl($routeParams, $location){
    //Assuming your params are an array like ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']
    //You could easily adapt this to base64 a JSON object
    function encodeParams(params){
        return window.btoa(params.join(';'));
    }

    function decodeParams(string){
        return window.atob(string).split(';');
    }

    var searchParams = decodeParams($routeParams.searchParams);

    scope.search = function(params){
        $location.path('/search/' + encodeParams(params));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution may be looks not so glad, but it's works at least:

You may organize your routs in way

```
yoursite.com/term1Name/**:param1**/term2Name/**:param2**/term3Name/**:param3**
```

To make it's clear, you may do your routes seems like REST routes. For example I'm want to go to a list of a services:

```
www.yoursite.com/servises/
```

Go to the one of the services:

```
www.yoursite.com/servise/:id
```

And if I'm want to see some of the service details, I'll do:

```
www.yoursite.com/servise/:id/details
```

and so

```
www.yoursite.com/servise/:id/detail/:id
```